# How come the NaN value is changing to float nan when i am accessing it by it's index ? How can i avoid it and keep it NaN as it was?

Tags: python, pandas, null, nan

[image: pandas issue]

can you please help me to understand why it is changing to nan (float)

Answer (score 1):

If you want `nan` as a literal string, use `fillna` to replace `nan` by `'NaN'`:

```
>>> df
        rase
0  {'A': 99}
1        NaN

>>> df = df.fillna('NaN')

>>> df['rase'][1]
'NaN'

>>> type(df['rase'][1])
str
```